# Dragon Heist: What is in Dalakhar's pouch?

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure, waterdeep-dragon-heist

I'm running Waterdeep: Dragon Heist, and early in chapter 3 there is a paragraph about Urstul fleeing the scene and that the players have a chance to pickpocket him. It also specifically says that the pouch belonged to Dalakhar.

What's in the pouch? I've skimmed the rest of the chapter but I didn't see it detailed, and some googling suggests that others also don't know and had to make something up on the spot.

It has to be the macguffin, right? This chapter is about putting the macguffin back in play so that all of the interested parties are scrambling for it. The one thing that Urstul has to take off of Dalakhar is the macguffin, but the rest of the chapter seems to assume that it was taken to the estate and that the players still not acquire it at the end of the chapter.

Well, my players have it now because that's what made sense to me in the moment, but I would like to know if there's an official word on the pouch's contents, or at least what the best ideas are from DMs that have run the adventure already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The section ["The Crime Scene"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/fireball#TheCrimeScene) states (emphasis mine):

> In the wake of the explosion, people emerge from their houses and shops to survey the devastation. The fireball didn’t set any buildings ablaze, but it left **eleven people dead**:
>
>  • [...]
>  • **One male gnome (Dalakhar)** wearing a burned cloak and clutching a dagger
>  • [...]
>
>  The characters have only a few minutes to search the crime scene before members of the City Guard arrive. [...] A search of the bodies accompanied by a successful DC 15 Wisdom (Perception) check reveals the following:
>
>  • [...]
>  • **The dead gnome** has dry waste on his boots and cloak, suggesting he has spent time in the sewers recently. **He also has a pouch containing five 100 gp gemstones.**
>
>  A character can try to snatch **Dalakhar’s pouch** without being seen by NPC onlookers, doing so with a successful DC 13 Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check.

My commentary, in spoiler block:

> Dalakhar is the only male gnome among the deceased, so "the dead gnome" with "a pouch containing five 100 gp gemstones" is referring specifically to Dalakhar.

Where is the Maguffin? We see previously in the section "Zhents Caught in the Act":

> Three members of the Black Network, including the Zhent assassin Urstul Floxin (see appendix B), were close to nabbing Dalakhar when they were caught in the blast. Of the three, only Urstul survived. Though he was wounded, **he was able to pluck the Stone of Golorr from Dalakhar’s pocket before fleeing the scene**. While other survivors were coming to their senses, Urstul stumbled through the smoke and haze and eventually made his way back to Gralhund Villa a short distance away.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow read over these sections a couple times and got something completely wrong from them.